# a simple function that loops an array to a specific index and then sums up all to the index found

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to sum all numbers before the index (param `x`) supplied to the function. So, for example, if we choose the index of 2, the result should be 1 + 2 = 3.

This is my (not working) code:

```js
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
let sum = 0;
function sumBeforeIndex(x) {
    for (let i=0; i < arr[x]; i++){
    sum += arr[i];
    return sum;
    }
};

console.log(sumBeforeIndex(2)); //x = chosing a random stop-on-index
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Ohh :D, the code isnt working :/

Comment: When you return inside a loop the loop will never complete, the return will occur on first iteration

Comment: If the function is called `sumBeforeIndex`, I'd assume an input of `2` to only sum `1+2` or, indeces `0` and `1` - the ones *before* index number `2`.

Comment: Ok, @Ori, but "It doesn't work" isn't a valid problem statement.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - he showed an example of code, defined what the result is supposed to be, and the problem is simple - it's not working. If he knew what's not working, he wouldn't have needed to ask the question in the 1st place. If you have a better problem statement, edit the answer, don't close.

Comment: Cheers charlie!

Comment: @RobertHarvey I've turned the code into a runnable snippet. I think that is all needed and it's clear now - there is a definition of what is supposed to be happening and a demonstration of what is actually happening.

Comment: @vlaz, yes that is correct. My bad! and to the rest of you. Thanks! <3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the return to the end of the function, and `i` should be less than `x` not `arr[x]`:

```js
function sumBeforeIndex(arr, x) {
  let sum = 0;
  
  for (let i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    sum += arr[i];
  }
  
  return sum;
};

let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];

console.log(sumBeforeIndex(arr, 2)); //x = chosing a random stop-on-index
```

You can also use [`Array.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) with [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
const sumBeforeIndex = (arr, index) =>
  arr.slice(0, index)
  .reduce((s, n) => s + n, 0);
  
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];

console.log(sumBeforeIndex(arr, 2)); //x = chosing a random stop-on-index
```

Answer (score 1):

This line is wrong:

```
//x could be any integer number and therefore be outside the bounds of the array, 
//and if x isn't outside the bounds of the array, 
//the number at that index could well be something other than what x is equal to
```

> for (let i=0; i < arr[x]; i++){

Should be this:

> for (let i=0; i <= x; i++){

as well as `return sum;` should be outside the `for-loop`